# Can't place aside tag to left top, have tried float: left / top:0, left:0 and other options still nothing

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the positioning of  tag in CSS. No matter what I try it remains below the main part and won't go on top (I need top right corner). Can't figure out where is the problem. Help, please.

Here is the problem part and my CSS code

```css
    .aside {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      margin: 14px 14px 14px 0px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      clear: left;
      width: 220px;
      background-color: #EAA845;
    }

    .sectionaside {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
      background-color: #DF5252;
    }
```

```html
<aside class="aside">

          <section class="sectionaside">
            <h4><u>Liked the article?! Stay tuned and find more interesting insights!</u></h4>
          
          </section>

          <section class="sectionaside">
            <h4>Related web sites</h4>
         
          </section>

          <section class="sectionaside">
            <h4>A &quot;must have&quot; skills in 21st century</h4>
            

          </section>

        </aside>


        <footer><u>Contact information</u></footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `position: absolute` (if it should be placed relative to `<body>`) or `position: fixed` (*sticks* to window) on tag with the `top` or `left` properties

Answer (score 1):

On your css, you are floating right under .aside, That needs to be changed to float: left; And its good practice to make clearfix after you finish floating elements. Check out the attached snippet with the changes on your code. Hope it helps.

```css
.aside {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 14px 14px 14px 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  clear: left;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #EAA845;
}

.sectionaside {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
  background-color: #DF5252;
}
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
    <aside class="aside">

      <section class="sectionaside">
        <h4><u>Liked the article?! Stay tuned and find more interesting insights!</u></h4>

      </section>

      <section class="sectionaside">
        <h4>Related web sites</h4>

      </section>

      <section class="sectionaside">
        <h4>A &quot;must have&quot; skills in 21st century</h4>


      </section>

    </aside>
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <footer><u>Contact information</u></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `aside`to be above everything else, just add `clear: both;` to whatever element comes after it  - in your particular case the footer, but in real life probably something else.

And if you really want it in the upper right corder, erase the `margin` setting for it and add `margin: 0;` to `html` and `body`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.aside {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 15px;
  clear: left;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #EAA845;
}

.sectionaside {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
  background-color: #DF5252;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">

  <section class="sectionaside">
    <h4><u>Liked the article?! Stay tuned and find more interesting insights!</u></h4>

  </section>

  <section class="sectionaside">
    <h4>Related web sites</h4>

  </section>

  <section class="sectionaside">
    <h4>A &quot;must have&quot; skills in 21st century</h4>


  </section>

</aside>


<footer><u>Contact information</u></footer>
```